# How do I query a query infinitely until a condition is reached in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server

I have a database with a table called Recipe, this table contains recipes and the materials that go into the recipes. I need a query that shows all the base materials for a recipe. Unfortunately, some of these materials are actually other recipes within the recipes. FOR EXAMPLE: you have recipe AA01 and within that it makes up 2 base materials and recipe BB01. You must now look up the materials in that recipe to find the base materials in AA01. The trick is, you can have an infinite amount of recipes within recipes. This can be a ladder of searching.
You don't know how far down the ladder you will have to look.

I came up with the idea of a query that searches and finds the next material and loops until it finally finds the base material. Sometimes it may have to loop once to find a material, other times it may have to loop 5 times to go down 5 levels.

The code below, unfortunately, I could not make it loop so it only finds the first layer. I could not make the query loop on itself.

```
SELECT 
    Recipe.RecipeID, 
    Recipe_1.RecipeID, 
    Recipe_1.MaterialID  
FROM Recipe 
LEFT JOIN Recipe AS Recipe_1 ON Recipe.MaterialID = Recipe_1.RecipeID
ORDER BY Recipe.RecipeID;
```

The solution would be to put this code in a loop or have it recursively call itself until it reaches a level where all base materials have been found. I have attached a picture of an example of a RECIPE table, what the code generates, and what I need it to generate (more levels) infinitely. You can see the highlighted rows are the ones missing from the actual one, those materials needed 2 levels to end up with the base materials. I have hard coded it to search up to 5 layers but obviously, there can be more. How can I have SQL loop and allocate the layers itself?

[image: here]

Is it possible to make a loop to continuously loop a query on itself?

Comment: If this is SQL Server, why have you tagged MySQL and Sequel?

Comment: Look up "Recursive CTE". That should help you out.

Comment: @JacobH I have and it just continued to print the same query

Comment: @SQLUser can you please post the CTE which you have tried?

Comment: I do not have it anymore sorry @Eli

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is producing the results you're looking for...

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Recipe', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Recipe;

CREATE TABLE #Recipe (
    Recipe VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    Material VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL 
    );

INSERT #Recipe (Recipe, Material) VALUES 
    ('aa01', 'B1'),
    ('aa01', 'B2'),
    ('aa01', 'bb01'),
    ('bb01', 'B1'),
    ('bb01', 'cc01'),
    ('cc01', 'B3'),
    ('cc01', 'B4'),
    ('B1', 'B1'),
    ('B2', 'B2'),
    ('B3', 'B3'),
    ('B4', 'B4');

--SELECT * FROM #Recipe r;

--====================================================================================

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RecursiveOutput', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #RecursiveOutput;

WITH 
    cte_Recursion AS (  
        SELECT 
            r.Recipe,
            x = r.Material,
            Material = CAST(r.Material AS VARCHAR(8000)),
            NodeLevel = 1,
            MaterialLevel = CAST('m1.Material' AS VARCHAR(8000))
        FROM
            #Recipe r
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            cr.Recipe, 
            x = r.Material,
            Material = CAST(CONCAT(cr.Material, '>', r.Material) AS VARCHAR(8000)),
            NodeLevel = cr.NodeLevel + 1,
            MaterialLevel = CAST(CONCAT('m', cr.NodeLevel + 1, '.Material, ', cr.MaterialLevel) AS VARCHAR(8000))
        FROM 
            cte_Recursion cr
            JOIN #Recipe r
                ON cr.x = r.Recipe
        WHERE 1 = 1
            AND cr.Recipe <> r.Recipe
            AND r.Recipe <> r.Material
        )
SELECT 
    cr.Recipe, 
    cr.Material, 
    cr.NodeLevel,
    cr.MaterialLevel
    INTO #RecursiveOutput
FROM
    cte_Recursion cr;

-------------------------------------

DECLARE 
    @Split VARCHAR(8000) = '',
    @Material VARCHAR(8000) = '',
    @Level VARCHAR(8000) = '',
    @SelectList VARCHAR(8000) = '', 
    @MaxNode INT = 0,
    @DeBug BIT = 0;     -- set to 0 to execute & set to 1 to print...


SELECT
    @Split = CONCAT(@Split, '
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(''>'', ro.Material, ', CASE WHEN ro.NodeLevel = 1 THEN '1' ELSE CONCAT('s', ro.NodeLevel - 1, '.Split + 1') END, '), 0)) ) s', ro.NodeLevel, ' (Split)'),
    @Material = CONCAT(@Material, '
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (SUBSTRING(ro.Material, ', CASE WHEN ro.NodeLevel = 1 THEN '1, ISNULL(s1.Split -1,' ELSE CONCAT('s', ro.NodeLevel - 1, '.Split + 1, ISNULL(s', ro.NodeLevel, '.Split - s', ro.NodeLevel - 1, '.Split - 1,') END, ' 1000))) ) m', ro.NodeLevel, ' (Material)'),
    @Level = CONCAT(@Level, CASE WHEN ro.NodeLevel = 1 THEN '' ELSE CONCAT('
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CAST(COALESCE(', ro.MaterialLevel, ') AS VARCHAR(20))) ) L', ro.NodeLevel, ' ([Level ', ro.NodeLevel, ' Material])') END),
    @SelectList =  CONCAT(@SelectList, CASE WHEN ro.NodeLevel = 1 THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(',
    L', ro.NodeLevel, '.[Level ', ro.NodeLevel, ' Material]') END),
    @MaxNode = CASE WHEN ro.NodeLevel > @MaxNode THEN ro.NodeLevel ELSE @MaxNode END
FROM 
    #RecursiveOutput ro
GROUP BY 
    ro.NodeLevel,
    ro.MaterialLevel;

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT('
SELECT DISTINCT
   ro.Recipe,
    [Level 1 Material] = CAST(m1.Material AS VARCHAR(20))', 
    @SelectList, '
FROM
    #RecursiveOutput ro', 
    @Split, 
    @Material,
    @Level, '
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Recipe r WHERE L', @MaxNode, '.[Level ', @MaxNode, ' Material] = r.Recipe AND r.Recipe = r.Material);')

IF @DeBug = 1
BEGIN 
    PRINT(@sql);
END;
ELSE 
BEGIN
    EXEC(@sql);
END;
```

Results...

```
Recipe Level 1 Material     Level 2 Material     Level 3 Material
------ -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
aa01   B1                   B1                   B1
aa01   B2                   B2                   B2
aa01   bb01                 B1                   B1
aa01   bb01                 cc01                 B3
aa01   bb01                 cc01                 B4
B1     B1                   B1                   B1
B2     B2                   B2                   B2
B3     B3                   B3                   B3
B4     B4                   B4                   B4
bb01   B1                   B1                   B1
bb01   cc01                 B3                   B3
bb01   cc01                 B4                   B4
cc01   B3                   B3                   B3
cc01   B4                   B4                   B4
```

Edit: Below is the same solution as above but written to eliminate the use of the CONCAT function for earlier versions of SQL Server...

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Recipe', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Recipe;

CREATE TABLE #Recipe (
    Recipe VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    Material VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL 
    );

INSERT #Recipe (Recipe, Material) VALUES 
    ('aa01', 'B1'),
    ('aa01', 'B2'),
    ('aa01', 'bb01'),
    ('bb01', 'B1'),
    ('bb01', 'cc01'),
    ('cc01', 'B3'),
    ('cc01', 'B4'),
    ('B1', 'B1'),
    ('B2', 'B2'),
    ('B3', 'B3'),
    ('B4', 'B4');

--SELECT * FROM #Recipe r;

--====================================================================================

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RecursiveOutput', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #RecursiveOutput;

WITH 
    cte_Recursion AS (  
        SELECT 
            r.Recipe,
            x = r.Material,
            Material = CAST(r.Material AS VARCHAR(8000)),
            NodeLevel = 1,
            MaterialLevel = CAST('m1.Material' AS VARCHAR(8000))
        FROM
            #Recipe r
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            cr.Recipe, 
            x = r.Material,
            Material = CAST(cr.Material + '>' + r.Material AS VARCHAR(8000)),
            NodeLevel = cr.NodeLevel + 1,
            MaterialLevel = CAST('m' + CAST(cr.NodeLevel + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.Material, ' + cr.MaterialLevel AS VARCHAR(8000))
        FROM 
            cte_Recursion cr
            JOIN #Recipe r
                ON cr.x = r.Recipe
        WHERE 1 = 1
            AND cr.Recipe <> r.Recipe
            AND r.Recipe <> r.Material
        )
SELECT 
    cr.Recipe, 
    cr.Material, 
    cr.NodeLevel,
    cr.MaterialLevel
    INTO #RecursiveOutput
FROM
    cte_Recursion cr;

-------------------------------------

DECLARE 
    @Split VARCHAR(8000) = '',
    @Material VARCHAR(8000) = '',
    @Level VARCHAR(8000) = '',
    @SelectList VARCHAR(8000) = '', 
    @MaxNode INT = 0,
    @DeBug BIT = 0;     -- set to 0 to execute & set to 1 to print...


SELECT
    @Split = @Split + '
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX(''>'', ro.Material, ' + CASE WHEN ro.NodeLevel = 1 THEN '1' ELSE 's' + CAST(ro.NodeLevel - 1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.Split + 1' END + '), 0)) ) s' + CAST(ro.NodeLevel AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' (Split)',

    @Material = @Material + '
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (SUBSTRING(ro.Material, ' + CASE WHEN ro.NodeLevel = 1 THEN '1, ISNULL(s1.Split -1,' ELSE 's' + CAST(ro.NodeLevel - 1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.Split + 1, ISNULL(s' + CAST(ro.NodeLevel AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.Split - s' 
            + CAST(ro.NodeLevel - 1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.Split - 1,' END + ' 1000))) ) m' + CAST(ro.NodeLevel as VARCHAR(10)) + ' (Material)',

    @Level = @Level + CASE WHEN ro.NodeLevel = 1 THEN '' ELSE '
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CAST(COALESCE(' + ro.MaterialLevel + ') AS VARCHAR(20))) ) L' + CAST(ro.NodeLevel AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ([Level ' + CAST(ro.NodeLevel as VARCHAR(10)) + ' Material])' END,

    @SelectList =  @SelectList + CASE WHEN CAST(ro.NodeLevel as VARCHAR(10)) = 1 THEN '' ELSE ',
    L' + CAST(ro.NodeLevel AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.[Level ' + CAST(ro.NodeLevel AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Material]' END,

    @MaxNode = CASE WHEN ro.NodeLevel > @MaxNode THEN ro.NodeLevel ELSE @MaxNode END
FROM 
    #RecursiveOutput ro
GROUP BY 
    ro.NodeLevel,
    ro.MaterialLevel;

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT DISTINCT
   ro.Recipe,
    [Level 1 Material] = CAST(m1.Material AS VARCHAR(20))' +
    @SelectList + '
FROM
    #RecursiveOutput ro' +
    @Split +
    @Material +
    @Level + '
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Recipe r WHERE L' + CAST(@MaxNode AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.[Level ' + CAST(@MaxNode AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Material] = r.Recipe AND r.Recipe = r.Material);'

IF @DeBug = 1
BEGIN 
    PRINT(@sql);
END;
ELSE 
BEGIN
    EXEC(@sql);
END;
```

HTH,
Jason

Comment: I dont seem to have the function CONCAT built in, in my SQL Server 2012..... how should I go about this

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2012 (not just SSMS 2012), you have the CONCAT function. If you execute "SELECT @@VERSION" what does it say?

Comment: surprisingly it says SQL Server 2005

Comment: I am unable to use any SQL Server greater than 2005. What is the best alternative to that built in function?

Comment: You can remove the CONCAT functions and simply concatenate the strings using the + operator.  Just keep in mind that the CONCAT function automatically converts non-string data types into VERCHARs and NULL values into empty strings... So you'll have to pay atention when making the change.

Comment: It looks like it does not like my concatenation skills, for example, it complains about this:  
Material = CAST(cr.Material + '>' + r.Material) AS VARCHAR(8000)  
Any help would greatly be appreciated, thanks! @Jason A. Long

Comment: I'll see if I can write up a non-CONCAT function version later today. I don't have time at the moment.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I was wondering if you had any time to create the non CONCAT version

Comment: Sorry for the long delay... I just added a new non-CONCAT version of the code to the bottom of my original answer.

Comment: I have been playing around with your declare and set part of the code. After fixing everything, I still get this error:  
  
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Line 11
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "L0.Level 0 Material" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "m1.Material" could not be bound.  

@Jason A. Long

Comment: Okay, so if you're in that section, I assume that you aren't having a problem with the recursive CTE. Just to be safe, check your output of #RecursiveOutput and compare it to the code I provided. If that part is off, you're wasting time messing with the code below it.
If you're 100% that we recursion part is where it needs to be, set the @DeBug variable to 1 in order to see the query that dynamic sql has built. Copy that over to a new SSMS tab and see what, if any, errors are produced. Again, compare the DeBug to the DeBug in the code I posted.

Comment: As far as the "String or binary data would be truncated", I'm not seeing a likely place for that to happen. Unless your levels are hundreds of level deep, I can't see any of the VARCHAR(8000) variables hitting a their limit, so I'm a little puzzled by that. The **"L0.Level 0 Material"** & **"L0.Level 0 Material"** leads me to believe that you tried to replace the square brackets with double quotes and put the leading double quote in the wrong place AND there shouldn't be any L0 or M0... All sections should start with 1.

Comment: There must be an easier way to do this, for example, you should be able to create a temp table of the list and then match each row's material to the identical recipe in the recipe table and then add those materials to the table. I am having an issue though when trying to match the material to the recipe in the other table because that recipe most likely has 2 or more materials and it errors saying it can only return one of them. @Jason A. Long

Comment: 'SELECT MaterialID FROM Recipe WHERE RecipeID = (SELECT TempMaterialID FROM @MaterialFound)'

     Will give me the error where it only can return one instead of multiple, any ideas around this

Comment: @SQLUser, That line of code does not exist antwhere in the example I provided. If you'd like to ask questions about the code **that I provided**, I'll do my best to explain. Changing my code and then asking why your changes don't work... My answer is, "don't change the code".

Comment: I am sorry I had to change it to be able to be used in SQL Server 2005, where declare variables must be set on a different line etc

Answer (score 0):

**Easy :)**

1. `Level = 1`
2. Create table variable with ingredients of top-level recipe (AA01) and mark records with `Level` (in separate column of your table variable)
3. While count of obtained records was greater than zero

   1. Increase Level
   2. Fetch all ingredients which have parent recipe among the ingredients found in previous step (`Level - 1`) and add them to the temporary table variable.
   3. Loop
4. At this moment you have the result. Level in table also indicates depth of given ingredient.

This avoids recursion and is computationally very cheap.

Just make sure that you detect circular path during adding the ingredients in `AFTER INSERT` trigger (and fail adding if it was detected) so recipe BB01 in recipe AA01 does not have subrecipe AA01. But this is achievable by the above approach, too, so it is not a big problem.

This code should do that (not tested, please report problems, if any):

```
DECLARE @RecipeID nchar(100) = 'AA01'; -- input - recipe you are searching for

-- initializations
DECLARE @RecipeDepth int = 0;
DECLARE @IngredientsFound TABLE (
    RecipeID NCHAR(100),
    MaterialID NCHAR(100),
    RecipeDepth int);
DECLARE @MAX_RECIPEDEPTH int = 100; -- constant for failsafe purposes

-- 0th step
INSERT INTO @IngredientsFound
    SELECT RecipeID, MaterialID, @RecipeDepth
        FROM Recipe
        WHERE RecipeID = @RecipeID;

-- following steps
WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND @RecipeDepth <= @MAX_RECIPEDEPTH)
BEGIN
    SET @RecipeDepth += 1;
    INSERT INTO @IngredientsFound
        SELECT RecipeID, MaterialID, @RecipeDepth
            FROM Recipe
            WHERE RecipeID IN (SELECT MaterialID
                                    FROM @IngredientsFound
                                    WHERE RecipeDepth = @RecipeDepth - 1);
END;

-- result
SELECT RecipeID, MaterialID, RecipeDepth
    FROM @IngredientsFound;
```

- instead of `Level` I used `RecipeDepth`, because the former one seems to be a reserved word or keyowrd
- I added a safeguard set 100 levels deep to prevent endless loop when there is a circular reference
- I finished every command with  `;` because in the future they intended to make them mandatory

Comment: @SQLUser – you do not need to expose it to common user, you can keep it only for your processing, where you need it

Comment: @SQLUser We call this a database key. A column that exists only for the database and is unknown by any end-user.

Comment: This is currently what I have for code, what have I done wrong ?

`DECLARE Level INT  
SET Level = 1  

DECLARE IngredientsFound TABLE (RecipeID NCHAR(100),MaterialID NCHAR(100))  

WHILE (ROWCOUNT > 0)  
BEGIN  
 SET Level = Level + 1  
 INSERT INTO IngredientsFound SELECT RecipeID, MaterialID  
        FROM Recipe WHERE RecipeID IN  
               (SELECT MaterialID FROM IngredientsFound   
               WHERE Recipe.[Level] = (Level - 1))  
END;  

SELECT RecipeID, MaterialID  
FROM IngredientsFound`  

@miroxlav

Comment: @miroxlav The code ran after a few tweaks but it was very hard to read since it would just query below itself, is there any way to add a column to the left each time it queries ? That way you can see kinda see parents and children?

Comment: @SQLUser – no, it is not made this way. The correct (and more practical) way to achieve that is to build the tree from data as you received them during presentation of results to user (either in application window or on the web page). `RecipeID` obtained in each row is your friend in this effort because it says who is the parent of each item. Then you just make it collapsible (or whatever) and you are ready to go. (Of course, based on that data, you can also build "wide table" you asked for, either in application or in the database. But it is different code, don't mess that inside this one.)

Comment: @SQLUser – so the answer is yes, it is possible to add column to the left, but not directly in this code, but rather by taking this result table into further processing and there you can add a column based on RecipeDepth or ParentID.

Comment: @miroxlav I still have not successfully finished this code, if you have any other ideas please let me know

Comment: @SQLUser – but is your code about adding of extra columns or are you happy with table with fixed number of columns which are expanded in client application, not in database? If you want extra columns, maybe you can go with the other answer.