# How can I insert a row at the bottom of a table while in a query?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

How can I delete the top row of a table and then add that same row (with updated information) to the bottom of the table?

In other words,

How can I insert a row at the bottom of a table while in a query?

Code Summary:

Loop (not included)

1. Selects the top row of the table 1
2. Using a query, update the row
3. Insert new updated row into table 2
4. Deletes the top row of table 1
5. Inserts updated row from table 2 into the table 1
6. Deletes all rows in table 2
7. Repeat ALL until all rows have been updated

Now, this should repeat for every row. But SOMETIMES the query decides the insert the updated row back to the top of the query so it continuously updates and deletes the same row over and over again. I am aware I can build another table and insert all the updated information into that BUT for this specific case, I need this updated information to go back into the same table so it can continuously update on itself.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @MaterialFound TABLE(
MasterRecipeID NCHAR(100),
TempRecipeID NCHAR(100),
TempMaterialID NCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @MaterialFound
(MasterRecipeID, TempRecipeID, TempMaterialID)
SELECT RecipeID, RecipeID, MaterialID
FROM Recipe

DECLARE @M TABLE(
MRID NCHAR(100),
RID NCHAR(100),
MID NCHAR(100));

--Display table
SELECT MasterRecipeID, TempRecipeID, TempMaterialID FROM @MaterialFound

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART--

--LOOP WHILE NOT ALL ARE UPDATED
INSERT INTO @M (MRID, RID, MID) 
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 MasterRecipeID FROM @MaterialFound), 
       (SELECT TOP 1 RecipeID FROM @MaterialFound), 
        MaterialID FROM Recipe WHERE RecipeID = 
       (SELECT TOP 1 TempMaterialID FROM @MaterialFound)

DELETE TOP(1)
FROM @MaterialFound

INSERT INTO @MaterialFound
(MasterRecipeID, TempRecipeID, TempMaterialID)
SELECT (MRID), (MID), MID
FROM @M

DELETE FROM @M

SELECT MasterRecipeID, TempRecipeID, TempMaterialID FROM @MaterialFound
--END LOOP
```

So how do I get the query to insert the new row at the bottom of the table EVERY TIME, assuming I have a loop implemented?

Comment: What's with the "bottom" of a table? additionally, why are you doing this in a loop? From your code sample, it would seem as if it can be done in a set-based fashion - thereby improving performance dramatically.

Comment: I need check each row in a table, the best way to do that in SQL would be to delete the top row each time and just adding it to the bottom. @Eli

Comment: you aren't showing any checking code in your sample - it seems like a simple migration from one table to another.

Comment: Why are you deleting the record in the first place instead of doing an update? A set based operation seems like the clear choice here unless I misunderstood some requirement.

Comment: Im sorry, I do not know what a set based operation is. This code is to my idea to solve this question here: 

[StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744039/how-do-i-query-a-query-infinitely-until-a-condition-is-reached-in-sql-server/45744199?noredirect=1#comment79090145_45744199)

Comment: As I suggested in that same very thread, a recursive CTE is still your best solution. You can use the recursive CTE for an update. Set-based means you are working with the entire data set in a single operation. Looping in SQL often results in extremely un-optimized code. Also, stop thinking in terms of "top" and "bottom" of tables. That concept doesn't really exist in SQL.

Comment: @JacobH I am seeing now how top and bottom do not really work. I tried CTE and it really hasnt worked out at all. I guess I will go back to it and try again.

Comment: @SQLUser why don't you post some sample data and what you've tried in terms of a CTE? This way someone here can guide you along if you get stuck.